# Calling str function in the expression in a cond statement cause a ClassCastException

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

If I setup a `cond` where the expression in a matched branch calls `(str)`, I get a `ClassCastException`. However, if I change that `str` to `format`the problem goes away.

**Code:**

```
(defn begins-with [chr str]
  (cond 
    (or (nil? str) (empty? str)) "Hey the string is empty!"
    (= (first str) chr) (str "found: " chr)
    :else "Didn't begin with the target char"))
```

**REPL:**

```
(begins-with \A "")
=> "Hey the string is empty!"

(begins-with \A "asdf")
=> "Didn't begin with the target char"

(begins-with \A "Apple")
ClassCastException java.lang.String cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  user/begins-with (form-init5132500100026084016.clj:4)
```

However, if I swap the `str` in the expression to a `format` everything works no problem

**Updated Code**

```
(defn begins-with [chr str]
  (cond 
    (or (nil? str) (empty? str)) "Hey the string is empty!"
    (= (first str) chr) (format "found: %s" chr)
    :else "Didn't begin with the target char"))
```

**REPL:**

```
(begins-with \A "Apple")
=> "found: A"
```

It suddenly works!!

Can anyone explain this behavior? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument is called `str` so it’s shadowing the core [`str`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/str) function.

`(str "found: " chr)` is thus evaluated as `("Apple" "found: " \A)`, which doesn’t work. Rename your variable to fix it.